# How to set-up mic for voice-over audio and minimize residual mouth noises

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I have a ATR2100x-USB mic from audio-technica. I've been recording some tutorial videos and overall like the sound quality.

But the inherent sensitivity of the mic picks up a lot of residual mouth noises. Like inhaling, exhaling, smacking, swallowing etc.

Is this a problem of mic placement? Audio settings? Lack of dampening equipment of some kind?

Not sure how to begin trouble shooting this problem.

Comment: Do you need this on camera? What distance are you speaking from? How close to on-axis are you?

Comment: Not on camera. I'd say I'm about 4-6 inches from the mic and I'm not sure what "on-axis" means I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

There is some good advice here : https://training.npr.org/2017/01/31/the-ear-training-guide-for-audio-producers/#recording

> How to avoid mouth noise:
>
> Changing mic placement can often help, especially if you are using a
> shotgun mic.
>
> Sipping apple juice is known to work well, as are eating Granny Smith
> apples. Remember that water can make this problem worse, as can coffee
> and milk-based products. Not everyone can keep apple juice on hand
> with them in the studio or out in the field, so you may want to advise
> your guests to avoid coffee and milk products prior to the interview.
>
> How to fix mouth noise:
>
> If you have a recording with egregious mouth noise, the de-crackle
> plugin included in Izotope RX can reduce the problem. Sometimes
> spectral repair tools can also work (you can find those in Izotope or
> Adobe Audition). That said, it may be helpful to seek the assistance
> of an audio expert.

Comment: I use scotch ;) More helpfully, Waves do a useful De-Breath plugin. Izotope also has De-plosive, Mouth De-click & Voice De-noise plugins.